# unwanted newline or empty symbols in g_strdup_printf

Tags: c, winapi, printf, glib

When using `data = g_strdup_printf("%.*s", len, buf)` where `guint len` and `gchar *buf`, I got string that seems to include newline symbol or some empty spaces..

I know it, because if I'll put this string in another one `g_strdup_printf("%s%s%s", "blah1", data, "blah2");` and print it in win32 `MessageBoxA()` - it will contain not `blah1datainsidesblah2` but

`blah1datainsides

blah2`

What is the possible reason and how can I fix this?

Important addition: I'm using `g_io_channel_read_line` to get those data and  seems that it gets data with included new-line character, if it is so, how can I get rid of it?

Comment: I would avoid using the ANSI API on WIN32 it is not maintained and behaves... interestingly. It's also missing a lot of functionality.

Comment: Thx for a tip, but truly I'm intrested not in using Glib itself, but in some libraries, built on top of it.

Comment: It looks like the input string includes a newline, so the duplicate of the input string also includes a newline. Unless you can show that the input string does not contain a newline, there's nothing untoward happening here.

Answer (score 0):

To remove trailing whitespace you can use [g_strchomp](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-strchomp).  For leading whitespace there is g_strchug, and for both leading and trailing g_strstrip.